# Simple timer, how to speak time intervals?

Tags: java, android, xml, timer, clock

I have a program where there is a twenty second timer running in the background (using service) I want to have the app log the amount of time left. For example, in five seconds, log "five seconds left!" The onTick method could be very useful in this, except the problem is it goes on regular intervals; so I may not be able to call out specific messages based on amount of time left. Here is my timer:

[image]

I would really appreciate a response, as I have been brainstorming ways to do this for a very long time now. If you need any more information, feel free to ask!

```
{Rich}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the onTick method you could do something like

```
int timeRemaining = 20000 - millisUntilFinished;
if(timeRemaining % 1000 == 0){
    Log.d("Time remaining", (timeRemaining % 1000) + " seconds left");
}
```

Since you already have a 1000 as your interval maybe that will help to skip the if block here.

If you are concerned about rounding your milliseconds to the nearest 1000 then maybe this will help
`MathUtils.round((double) timeRemaining, -3);`
The second parameter here helps to select the precision for rounding off, -1 for tens, -2 for hundreds and -3 for 1000s and so on.

All the best :)

Comment: Thanks so much! For some reason, the logs aren't displaying. Do you know why? Here it is: 
http://snag.gy/MzFxG.jpg

Comment: Try this. 
int timeRemaining = 20000 - millisUntilFinished;
timeRemaining = (int)MathUtils.round((double) timeRemaining, -3);
Log.d("Time remaining", (timeRemaining % 1000) + " seconds left");

Comment: Thanks, I marked you best answer and liked your answer!